# My web app will not send confirmation emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sendgrid, confirmation

My app used to send email confirmations when you created an account login. But I reset my database with rake db:reset and now when i Create a new account i never receive and email confirmation. Therefore I cant login into my app.

Here is my github
https://github.com/goldmullet/bloccit

Comment: PS. I am using Sendgrid for my email client

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following lines in /config/production.rb to send through SMTP:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
      port: 587,
      authentication: "plain",
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
  }
```